# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS very long X session login due to 90xbrlapi

Tags: login, xorg, 22.04

I have a problem on my desktop where login takes a minute or two. During that time the screen stays black. I have checked `syslog` and found a quite large time gap when the X session runs `/etc/gdm3/Xsession`. I then further added a debug line to the part when it loads `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` like so:

```bash
if [ -d /etc/X11/Xsession.d ]; then
    for i in `ls /etc/X11/Xsession.d/` ; do
        if [ -r "/etc/X11/Xsession.d/$i"  -a -f "/etc/X11/Xsession.d/$i" ] && expr "$i" : '^[[:alnum:]_-]\+$' > /dev/null; then
            # trying to debug long login times
            echo "Running $i"
        . "/etc/X11/Xsession.d/$i"
        fi
    done
fi
```

This allows me to have the following logs in `syslog`:

```
Jan  3 10:50:41 bellamy /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[182953]: Running 90qt-a11y
Jan  3 10:50:41 bellamy /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[183003]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
Jan  3 10:50:41 bellamy /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[182953]: Running 90x11-common_ssh-agent
Jan  3 10:50:41 bellamy /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[182953]: Running 90xbrlapi
Jan  3 10:50:59 bellamy systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  3 10:50:59 bellamy systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  3 10:50:59 bellamy systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  3 10:51:29 bellamy geoclue[182674]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Jan  3 10:51:29 bellamy systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  3 10:52:40 bellamy xbrlapi.desktop[182796]: openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
Jan  3 10:52:40 bellamy xbrlapi.desktop[182796]: cannot connect to braille devices daemon brltty at :0
Jan  3 10:52:52 bellamy /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[182953]: Running 95dbus_update-activation-env
Jan  3 10:52:52 bellamy /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[183035]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
```

So I tried changing the value for `QT_ACCESSIBILITY` or commenting everything in `90qt-a11y` but it still takes a long time or makes login impossible. I've searched for resources on how to uninstall/disable accessibility features but haven't found out what packages are safe to remove.

I have trouble finding more leads on how to solve this problem now, so do you have any recommendations of other logs I should check or packages I should fix/uninstall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay so while I wrote this I noticed that I focused on the `90qt-a11y` script while the culprit was `90xbrlapi`. Editing that file to comment everything in it got my login times back to normal!

Comment: It was months I was looking for a solution to this problem, and this was the solution. I believe that many  similar other questions without a definitive answer, should point to this answer.